# Reading JSON file with BigQuery to make table

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to Google Dataflow, and can't get this thing to work with JSON. I've been reading throughout the documentation, but can't solve my problem.

So, following the WordCount example i figured how data is loaded from .csv file with next line

```
PCollection<String> input = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(options.getInputFile()));
```

where inputFile in .csv file from my gcloud bucket. I can transform read lines from .csv with:

```
PCollection<TableRow> table = input.apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractParametersFn()));
```

(Extract ParametersFn defined by me). So far so good!

---

But then I realize my .csv file is too big and had to convert it to JSON (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery). 
Since BigQueryIO is supposedly better for reading JSON, I tried with the following code:

```
 PCollection<TableRow> table = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.from(options.getInputFile()));
```

(inputFile is then JSON file and the output when reading with BigQuery is PCollection with TableRows) I tried with TextIO too (which returns PCollection with Strings) and neither of the two IO options work.

What am I missing? The documentation is really not that detailed to find an answer there, but perhaps some of you guys already dealt with this problem before?

Any suggestions would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: afaik your input file rows must be separated as lines (carriage return) im not sure you can do that with json

Comment: When you say doesn't work... it crashes? Returns wrong data? What error do you see, etc?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are two options to consider:

1. Use TextIO with TableRowJsonCoder to ingest the JSON files (e.g., like it is done in the [TopWikipediaSessions example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TopWikipediaSessions.java#L217));
2. Import the JSON files into a bigquery table (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery), and then use [BigQueryIO.Read](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io#reading) to read from the table.